# Find the value of $abc-a^2-b^2-c^2$ if $x,y,z$ are given in terms or $a,b,c$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> if $$x=\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}$$
>     $$y=\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{b}$$
>   $$z=\frac{c}{a}+\frac{a}{c}$$
>   Then find
>   $$abc-a^2-b^2-c^2$$

As there are 6 variables in terms of 3 , we can fix any three without violating the conditions.
Say if $a=b=c=2$ then clearly the answer is$-4$ but how to find it in pure algebric way.

Comment: If $a=b=c=2$, then the answer is $-4$?.

Comment: @MDesmond You cannot just assign values to $a,b,c$... Looking at the question as it is presented, the only thing that makes sense to me is computing $abc-a^2-b^2-c^2$ in terms of $x,y,z$. Maybe you could post the exact original question?

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan yes, just corrected it.

Comment: You cannot determine the value of $abc-a^2-b^2-c^2$ given just the values of $x,y,z$. Indeed, note that if you doubled each of $a,b,c$, then $x,y,z$ wouldn't change, while $abc-a^2-b^2-c^2$ would.

Comment: The question is not clear. What do you have and what do you want?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to find $xyz-x^2-y^2-z^2.$

If so:
$$xyz-\sum_{cyc}x^2=\prod_{cyc}\left(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}\right)-\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}\right)^2=$$
$$=\frac{\prod\limits_{cyc}(a^2+b^2)}{a^2b^2c^2}-\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{a^2}{b^2}+\frac{b^2}{a^2}\right)-6=$$
$$=\frac{\sum\limits_{cyc}\left(a^4b^2+b^4a^2+\frac{2}{3}a^2b^2c^2\right)}{a^2b^2c^2}-\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{a^2}{b^2}+\frac{b^2}{a^2}\right)-6=2-6=-4.$$
In the full writing it's the following:
$$xyz-x^2-y^2-z^2=$$
$$=\frac{(a^2+b^2)(a^2+c^2)(b^2+c^2)}{a^2b^2c^2}-\left(\frac{a^2}{b^2}+\frac{b^2}{a^2}+\frac{a^2}{c^2}+\frac{c^2}{a^2}+\frac{b^2}{c^2}+\frac{c^2}{b^2}+6\right)=$$
$$=\frac{a^4b^2+a^4c^2+b^4a^2+b^4c^2+c^4a^2+c^4b^2+2a^2b^2c^2}{a^2b^2c^2}-$$
$$-\left(\frac{a^2}{b^2}+\frac{b^2}{a^2}+\frac{a^2}{c^2}+\frac{c^2}{a^2}+\frac{b^2}{c^2}+\frac{c^2}{b^2}+6\right)=$$
$$=\left(\frac{a^2}{b^2}+\frac{b^2}{a^2}+\frac{a^2}{c^2}+\frac{c^2}{a^2}+\frac{b^2}{c^2}+\frac{c^2}{b^2}+2\right)-$$
$$-\left(\frac{a^2}{b^2}+\frac{b^2}{a^2}+\frac{a^2}{c^2}+\frac{c^2}{a^2}+\frac{b^2}{c^2}+\frac{c^2}{b^2}+6\right)=2-6=-4.$$

Comment: In an ealier post, you mentioned one or two books that you liked for such answers. Can you please tell me what those books were?

Comment: @Moo I don't remember. Ask your question. I am ready to explain.

Comment: Someone had asked in a comment, what books you'd recommend for inequalities, AM/GM and learning these types of approaches. You mentioned two older books by a single author IIRC. I cannot find the post where you listed those.

Comment: I like books of Vasile Cyrtoaje.

Comment: That was it, thanks a bunch!

Comment: If you write $p=a/b,q=b/c,r=c/a$, then we have $x=p+p^{-1}$ etc. and using $pqr$ the proof simplifies quite a bit

Comment: @Wojowu Yes, of course. The idea is the same.

Comment: Can you explain the last step,how you got '2' ?

Comment: @M Desmond I added something, See now.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, you can't find $abc-a^2-b^2-c^2$ given $x,y,z$ as stated, since the latter equations imply that $x,y,z$ are algebraically dependent. Indeed, there exists a constant $C$ such that

$$xyz-x^2-y^2-z^2=C\text{.}$$

Comment: But the objective is to found $abc-a^2-b^2-c^2$ not **$xyz-x^2-y^2-z^2$**